# appassembler-maven-plugin add custom entry to classpath

Tags: java, maven, classpath, maven-assembly-plugin

I'm writing a Java-Application which is using some libaries from anonther thirdparty-Application which is running on my server. At the moment im building my App with the appassembler-maven-plugin. This plugin copy my jars (app and dependencies) into the lib folder an generates a shellscript in the bin dir.

The classpath is generated in this shellscirpt. This solution works but i dublicate the dependency-jars (on time in my app and in the thirdparty-Application write the app for). The classpath of my thirdparty-application is set in a systemvariable like $THIRDPARTYAPP_CLASSPATH.

I want to set the dependencies in my pom.xml to provided, so that the appassembler don't add them to lib and classpath and want to add the systemvar $THIRDPARTYAPP_CLASSPATH in my shellscript, so that my app uses the jars from the installed thirdparty-application.

At the moment i'm doing this manually (editing the shellscript after the build) and it works. Is there any method in the appassembler-maven-plugin to add thid systemvar to the classpath automatically?

I couldn't find anything in the documentation and other questions here regarding a similar problem are not well answerd.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>assemble</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <assembleDirectory>${project.build.directory}/appassembler</assembleDirectory>
        <extraJvmArguments>-Xms512m -Xmx1024m</extraJvmArguments>
        <generateRepository>true</generateRepository>
        <repositoryName>lib</repositoryName>
        <repositoryLayout>flat</repositoryLayout>
        <includeConfigurationDirectoryInClasspath>true</includeConfigurationDirectoryInClasspath>
        <platforms>
            <platform>unix</platform>
        </platforms>
        <programs>
            <program>
                <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
                <id>app</id>
            </program>
        </programs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: First why are configuring the defaults `assembleDirectory`? You can configure to create an `<environmentSetupFileName>setup-env</environmentSetupFileName>` which can define a new classpath part via `CLASSPATH_PREFIX ` which should solve your problem. (BTW: why not using an uptodate version of appassembler?)...

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly what i was looking for. And thanks for the hint regarding version and directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure to create an `<environmentSetupFileName>setup-env</environmentSetupFileName>` which can define a new classpath part via `CLASSPATH_PREFIX` which should solve your problem.